# aligning form elements bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can't seem to horizontally align my form elements with bootstrap 3. I tried adding ***.form-inline*** but still no results. Heres my form.

```
 <form>
    <input type="input" />
    <select></select>
    <select name="something">
        <option value="1">1</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing `<div class="form-group">` around your form elements and you need to add a `form-control` class to your fields. From the docs:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline